# run two Angular functions from the same popup window

Tags: javascript, angular

Would you recommend somthinglike this if I need to run 2 functions, Assign1 and Assign2 from the same popup window? If either one gives an error, the window will close without saving anything. If 
Not too sure about syntax.

```
function Assign() {
    Assign1().then(function(isSuccess) {
        if (isSuccess) {
            Assign2();
            saveAndClose();
        } else {
            CloseAndShowError();
        }
    }, function() {
        CloseAndShowError();
    });

}
```

I should specify  that Assign1 and Assign2 are made with promises in their definitions and I need to know if overall the calls are successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $q.all();
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all

This method allows you to run more than one promise as if it was a single one.

So, inside your Assign() method, there could be the following code.

```
let promisesToBeRunned = [Assign1, Assign2];
$q.all(promisesToBeRunned)
    .then(
        () => {doYourSuccessStuff();}),
        CloseAndShowError)
    );
```

If both promises are successful, the success callback will be executed.

If one of the promises, either Assign1 or Assign2 fails, the error callback will be called.

*NOTE* : Try to use $q.reject() on Assign1, so you won't have to use 
`if (isSuccess)`. Maybe if you post the Assign1 definition, I could give you an idea.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
function1() {
  //function1 body
}

function2() {
  //function2 body
}
```

In `template` call them as

```
<button (click)="function1();function2()"> </button>
```